# Simple backbone.js issue

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

For the life of me I cannot figure out why this isnt working...

It retrieves backbone and underscore no problem, and will not propagate any errors, but it also will not output hello world to the console.

```
<body>
 <script src="D:/underscore.js"></script>
 <script src="D:/"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">

  Person = Backbone.Model.extend({
     initialize: function() {
        console.log('hello world');
    }
});


</script>

</body>
</head>
```

Comment: you are not creating a new Person, like that `new Person` :)

Answer (score 3):

You need to create a new Person.  All that you have done at this point is specify the properties of the Person model.  So add:

```
var myPerson = new Person();
```

At the end of your script tag.  And that should work.

Comment: In the tutorial I am watching it outputs hello world no matter what. Also when I add that is says: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Comment: http://backbonetutorials.com/what-is-a-model/  It took me a while to also understand it.  I think that it is in the tutorial or not being shown.

Comment: Thanks for the help, both of you. I have no idea why, but I deleted the variable I was sending in with it and retyped them and it works. I looked over them a hundred times I didn't see any spelling errors. Bleh, but working now. Thanks again!